# Combining TWO actions within a static HTML form on POST

Tags: javascript, html

I am using this great app called Web3Forms that basically allows you to easily send email using a static HTML form.

The app allows you to send the data to an email account but I would like to do that AND also send the data to Zapier via a webhook.

Here's my HTML that I thought would work by combining two functions and using Javascript (I tweaked this code from another post on StackOverflow).

```
<form id="signupForm" action="" method="POST">

  <input type="hidden" name="apikey" value="XXXXXXXXX">

  <!-- Optional: Can be type="hidden" or type="text" for subject -->
  <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="New Submission Form">

  <!-- If javascript, use "window.location.hash" for redirects -->
  <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="https://web3forms.com/success">

  <!-- Optional: But Recommended: To Prevent SPAM Submission.
       Make sure its hidden by default -->
  <input type="checkbox" name="botcheck" id="" style="display: none;">

  <!-- Google reCaptcha v3: To Prevent SPAM Submission.PRO Plan only -->
  <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response" id="recaptchaResponse">

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="First Name" class="form-control-input" id="rname" required>
        <label class="label-control" for="rname">Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="Occupation" class="form-control-input" id="roccupation" required>
        <label class="label-control" for="roccupation">Your Role</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control-input" id="remail" required>
        <label class="label-control" for="remail">Email</label>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="form-group checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="rterms" value="Agreed-to-Terms" required>I agree with the website's <a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a> and <a href="terms.html">Terms & Conditions</a>
    </div> -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="form-control-submit-button" onclick="sendDATA()" />TELL ME MORE</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
<script>
form=document.getElementById("signupForm");
function sendDATA() {
    form.action="https://api.web3forms.com/submit";
    form.action="https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/XXXX/YYYY/";
    form.submit();
}
</script>
```

Is this approach possible? Am I missing something?

Thanks for all pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Not like that.
You will need to set up 2 separate ajax POST calls, sending the same data to both.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, remove the `onClick` on the button, so we can handle it in JavaScript.

On the JS side, you'll need to make two requests, passing the same form data to each request. In this case, we can use [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to make each request, and create a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/FormData) to get the data from the form easily.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  form = document.getElementById("signupForm");

  function sendData(url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var formData = new FormData(form);

    xhr.open("POST", url);
    xhr.send(formData);
  }
  
  form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    sendData("https://api.web3forms.com/submit");
    sendData("https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/XXXX/YYYY/");
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="signupForm" action="" method="POST">

  <input type="hidden" name="apikey" value="XXXXXXXXX">

  <!-- Optional: Can be type="hidden" or type="text" for subject -->
  <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="New Submission Form">

  <!-- If javascript, use "window.location.hash" for redirects -->
  <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="https://web3forms.com/success">

  <!-- Optional: But Recommended: To Prevent SPAM Submission.
       Make sure its hidden by default -->
  <input type="checkbox" name="botcheck" id="" style="display: none;">

  <!-- Google reCaptcha v3: To Prevent SPAM Submission.PRO Plan only -->
  <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response" id="recaptchaResponse">

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="First Name" class="form-control-input" id="rname" required>
        <label class="label-control" for="rname">Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="Occupation" class="form-control-input" id="roccupation" required>
        <label class="label-control" for="roccupation">Your Role</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control-input" id="remail" required>
        <label class="label-control" for="remail">Email</label>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="form-group checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="rterms" value="Agreed-to-Terms" required>I agree with the website's <a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a> and <a href="terms.html">Terms & Conditions</a>
    </div> -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="form-control-submit-button"/>TELL ME MORE</button>
    </div>
</form>
```